# Object doesn't support property or method [Casual javascript error on SharePoint site]

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I've been trying to find a reason for this error. The weird thing is that it only occurs on 1 specific page. The page contains nothing but the ribbon, global nav, quicklaunch, a content editor webpart, and a visual webpart displaying a asp.net login control.

*It works on all other pages, except this single page.*

This script is what it returns an error on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sn2-bodyContainer").SetHeightEqualTo(window, true);
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("#sn2-bodyContainer").SetHeightEqualTo(window, true);
    });
});
```

This is the SetHeightEqualTo function, which it claims is not existing/cannot be found.

```
var calculate = {
    height: function (DOM) {
        return $(DOM).height();
    },
    width: function (DOM) {
        return $(DOM).width();
    },
    extractRibbonHeight: function (DOM) {
        return $(DOM).height() - 44;
    }
};

// @equalTo : The element height which should be replicated.
// @isMain : True/False value determining whether it's the main container div or not being manipulated.
$.fn.SetHeightEqualTo = function (equalTo, isMain) {
    if ($(".ms-dialog").find("body.snmaster").length == 0) {
        if (isMain) {
            this.css('min-height', calculate.extractRibbonHeight(equalTo));
        }
        else {
            this.height(calculate.height(equalTo))
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well youre missing a `;`:

`this.height(calculate.height(equalTo))`

If thats not just a typo in your post then you should be getting a parse error which would make the function not exist. But then it should fail on any page where you use it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I added it. But the error still persists.

Comment: While good coding practice, `;` are not (technically) required, and I've never seen them cause a parse error.